# Spring WebClient extract JsonPath value

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-webflux, spring-kotlin

I'm using Spring 5 [WebClient test features](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#webtestclient) and would like to extract body matched by the `jsonPath` expression but can't find any suitable way of doing it. For example (the code is in Kotlin but I hope this doesn't make any difference):

```
client!!.get().uri("/app/metrics")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.names")
                .isArray
```

The actual json body is:

```
{
"names": [
"jvm.buffer.memory.used",
"jvm.memory.used",
"jvm.buffer.count",
"jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
"logback.events",
"process.uptime",
"jvm.memory.committed",
"system.load.average.1m",
"jvm.gc.max.data.size",
"jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
"jvm.memory.max",
"system.cpu.count",
"jvm.threads.daemon",
"system.cpu.usage",
"jvm.threads.live",
"process.start.time",
"jvm.threads.peak",
"jvm.gc.live.data.size",
"jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
"process.cpu.usage"
]
}
```

So I'd like to get list of names into list variable and use it. Is there any way to do it with current `jsonPath` support?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (tried with `springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'`):

```
client.get().uri("/app/metrics")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().isOk
    .expectBody()
    .jsonPath("$.names")
    .value<JSONArray> { json ->
        json.toList().forEach { println(it) }
    }
```

will print:

```
jvm.buffer.memory.used
jvm.memory.used
jvm.buffer.count
jvm.gc.memory.allocated
logback.events
process.uptime
jvm.memory.committed
system.load.average.1m
jvm.gc.max.data.size
jvm.buffer.total.capacity
jvm.memory.max
system.cpu.count
jvm.threads.daemon
system.cpu.usage
jvm.threads.live
process.start.time
jvm.threads.peak
jvm.gc.live.data.size
jvm.gc.memory.promoted
process.cpu.usage
```